# Request for XSLT scenario to populate multple records

Tags: xslt

I am working on an XSLT map to generate the target structure of what is being sent in the source field OUTPUT_XML.

**This is my source structure which has two rows**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ns0:Customer xmlns:ns0="urn:customer">
   <row>
      <OUTPUT_XML><response><test>123</test></response></OUTPUT_XML>
   </row>
   <row>
      <OUTPUT_XML><response><test>456</test></response></OUTPUT_XML>
   </row>
</ns0:Customer>
```

**XSLT Code**

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8' ?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:ns0="urn:customer" >

    <xsl:template match="/">

            <xsl:value-of select="ns0:Customer/row/OUTPUT_XML" disable-output-escaping="yes"/>

    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

With this code, I always get output of only 1st record as shown below.

**XSLT output**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<response>
   <test>123</test>
</response>
```

Can you please advise the xslt code to populate multiple records.

**Expected output**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<response>
   <test>123</test>
   <test>456</test>
</response>
```

Comment: Can you please present a clearer question.   The output is not possible for the xsl you have given and the xsl is incomplete. The xsl:value-of is not used to create xml tags and even if it could do anything like that, it would've created a result that was not well-formed based on your input.

Comment: Hi Phil, Thanks for the reply. Its currently working with the code, I provided.Since the value in the field is under CDATA tags.

Comment: @VarunReddyK Please post a **representative** example. If the input XML contains CDATA sections, show them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the xsl to this...

```
<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="ns0:Customer/row/OUTPUT_XML"/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="OUTPUT_XML">
   <xsl:value-of select="." disable-output-escaping="yes"/>
</xsl:template>
```

The output method would need to be **text** for this to work becuase the result will not be well-formed for multiple row/OUTPUT_XML

If you want xml out, then you'll need to include a root node in the output

```
<xsl:template match="/">
   <e>
       <xsl:apply-templates select="ns0:Customer/row/OUTPUT_XML"/>
   </e>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="OUTPUT_XML">
   <xsl:value-of select="." disable-output-escaping="yes"/>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Thanks phil, your code worked. But I think i did a mistake here.. response is a root node so, it should be repeated

Comment: @ Phil - Can you pls suggest what changes to be made to get the desired output

Comment: "*The output method would need to be text for this to work becuase the result will not be well-formed for multiple row/OUTPUT_XML*" No. The result of an XSLT transformation *can* be a result tree fragment.

Comment: For clarifcation - is the output_xml truely CDATA? Its an important point.  If it is cdata, is there anyway you can stream the input into the xsl processor such that is is pure xml?

Answer (score 0):

Try it this way:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
xmlns:ns0="urn:customer" 
exclude-result-prefixes="ns0">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:template match="/ns0:Customer">
    <response>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </response>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="row">
    <test>
        <xsl:value-of select="OUTPUT_XML/response/test" />
    </test>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Or, if you prefer:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
xmlns:ns0="urn:customer" 
exclude-result-prefixes="ns0">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/ns0:Customer">
    <response>
        <xsl:for-each select="row">
            <test>
                <xsl:value-of select="OUTPUT_XML/response/test" />
            </test>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </response>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: -- the input content node OUTPUT_XML contains  CDATA.  Yes, I know it isn't clear in the question but it was pointed out in a response to one of my comments.

Comment: @PhilB Well, it depends on what exactly the CDATA is. Let the OP edit the question and show us.